# racket match syntax quasiquote and question mark

Tags: lisp, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am trying to understand pattern match document of racket and have some questions like the following, I can't parse it.

- (quasiquote qp) — introduces a quasipattern, in which identifiers match symbols. Like the quasiquote expression form, unquote and unquote-splicing escape back to normal patterns.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html

Example:

```
> (match '(1 2 3)
    [`(,1 ,a ,(? odd? b)) (list a b)])

'(2 3)
```

It doesn't explain this example, and how "identifiers match symbols"? I guess it is match `'(1 2 3)` to pattern `'(1, a, b)` and b is odd, but why `` `(,1 ,a ,(? odd? b)) `` not `` `(1 a (? odd? b)) ``, whey it needs commas in between list members? Especially `` `(, ``? Why that way?  So string!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you're not familiar with quasiquoting, then you might to get comfortable with `list` patterns in `match`, then learn about quasiquoting in general. Then putting the two together will be easier to understand.

Why? Because quasiquote is "only" a shorthand or alternative for what you can write with `list`. Although I don't know the actual development history, I imagine that the author(s) of `match` started off with patterns like `list`, `cons`, `struct` and so on. Then someone pointed out, "hey, sometimes I prefer to describe a `list` using quasiquoting" and they added quasiquoting, too.

```
#lang racket

(list 1 2 3)
; '(1 2 3)
'(1 2 3)
; '(1 2 3)

(define a 100)
;; With `list`, the value of `a` will be used:
(list 1 2 a)
; '(1 2 100)
;; With quasiquote, the value of `a` will be used:
`(1 2 ,a)
; '(1 2 100)
;; With plain quote, `a` will be treated as the symbol 'a:
'(1 2 a)
; '(1 2 a)

;; Using `list` pattern
(match '(1 2 3)
  [(list a b c) (values a b c)])
; 1 2 3

;; Using a quasiquote pattern that's equivalent:
(match '(1 2 3)
  [`(,a ,b ,c) (values a b c)])
; 1 2 3

;; Using a quote pattern doesn't work:
(match '(1 2 3)
  ['(a b c) (values a b c)])
; error: a b c are unbound identifiers

;; ...becuase that pattern matches a list of the symbols 'a 'b 'c
(match '(a b c)
  ['(a b c) #t])
; #t
```